# Parallel.ForEach Freezing during final iterations

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library

This is my first time working with `Parrllel.ForEach` and I am having a issue. It is a shame because i really needed performance out of this program and I was getting it.

I would say in its last iterations my ForEach is freezing. This is not exposing any error messages. The `ConsoleWriteLine()` comes to a halt. When I pause in the debugger the scope of  `Parallel.ForEach` is highlighted.

```
   using (DBDataContext db = DataContextFactory.GetThreadScopedDataContext<DBDataContext>())
            {
                products = (from r in db.tbl_products
                           where r.date >= _dateCheck
                           select r

                ).ToList();

                int rcount = products.Count();

                Console.WriteLine("Total products: {0}", rcount);

                Parallel.ForEach(products, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, product =>
                {
                    DBDataContext db2 = DataContextFactory.GetThreadScopedDataContext<DBDataContext>();


                    CheckInventory(product, db2);


                });

                Console.WriteLine("Ended Inventory Check {0}", DateTime.Now);
            }
```

The last phase of the CheckInventory() method is to create a record of the match

```
  private static void AddNewInventoryMatch(tbl_product product, tbl_inventory item, int matchType)
        {


            DBDataContext db = DataContextFactory.GetThreadScopedDataContext<DBDataContext>("4");

            tbl_inventoryMatch newMatch = new tbl_inventoryMatch();
          //... Add records



            db.tbl_inventoryMatches.InsertOnSubmit(newMatch);
            //  db.SubmitChanges();


        }
```

I have looked all over the web to try and find what could be causing this and I have had no luck. This is a simple console app that would run nightly.

Also after it locks up VS Cannot compile the project unless i restart VS. I get this error message.

```
Error   11  Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\Inventory-Match.exe" to "bin\Debug\Inventory-Match.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  Inventory-Match
Error   12  Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Inventory-Match.exe" to "bin\Debug\Inventory-Match.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Inventory-Match.exe' because it is being used by another process. Inventory-Match
```

Links:
DataContextFactory = http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management

Comment: How many products do you have? May be your dataContext is getting too bigger and you need to clean it.

Comment: @MarcCals it can vary based on the day 1-6. Which i know that doesn't sound like a lot but a product can have 1000's of codes that have to get compared against the inventory.   Also there is over 1 million Inventory files and growing.

Comment: @PetSerAl a typo when i was trying to move the code into the question.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @MarcCals Linq to SQL

Comment: I don't know if it can be the same but with Entity Framework, Database context performance degrade with it use, if you load lot of Entities, may be this affect to Linq to Sql too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem long time ago, try using `GetDataContext` instead of `GetThreadScopedDataContext`